# Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl" - Oracle Linux

Tags: repository, oracle-linux, url

The OS of my machine is Oracle Linux Server 7.5.

I need to install a command via a repository, precisely `yum --enablerepo=packages-microsoft-com-prod install mdatp`, but I get errors like:

```
libatomic-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libnetfilter_queue-1.0.2-2.el7_2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I used the command `yum repolist` and it reported this to me:

```
Repository 'ol7_software_collections': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'file:///run/media/root/OL7.5 Server.src/'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
```

I went on **/etc/yum.repos.d/** and I found:

- media.repo
- prod.repo
- public-yum-ol7.repo
- public-yum-ol7.repoold

I opened the file **public-yum-ol7.repo**

```
[ol7_software_collections]
name=OracleLinux7
baseurl=file:///run/media/root/OL7.5 Server.src/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I can't find the error, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That error likely results from the whitespace in the path to the repo; quote it in some way:

- With a backslash: `baseurl=file:///run/media/root/OL7.5\ Server.src`

or

- with a "%20": `baseurl=file:///run/media/root/OL7.5%20Server.src`

or

- with single quotes: `baseurl='file:///run/media/root/OL7.5 Server.src'`

or

- with double quotes: `baseurl="file:///run/media/root/OL7.5 Server.src"`

The URL value is parsed with the urlparse python library here:
https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/yum/config.py#L230
and if that fails, it prints the "URL must be %s not "%s" error string.

The book [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7: Desktops and Administration](https://books.google.com/books?id=PrYuDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA8-PA33&lpg=SA8-PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false) also mentions the single-quotes or backslash methods:

> Enclose the entire reference in single quotes so that the empty space after the RHEL-7.3 can be read, or place a backslash before the space.

An older reference, with answers from 2008, is the [How to write a the baseurl of a path that has spaces](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-write-a-the-baseurl-of-a-path-that-has-spaces-668560/) page, which mentions:

> - baseurl=file:///media/Fedora%208%20i386%20DVD/Packages
> - baseurl=file:///media/Fedora\ 8\ i386\ DVD/Packages
> - baseurl="file:///media/Fedora 8 i386 DVD/Packages"

(although those attempts appear to have failed for that OP)

Comment: Thank you so much! I answer you in my next post that unfortunately I was not able to solve the problem :(

Comment: I saw your comment, thank you. I try to fix the repositories!

Comment: Hi Jeff Schaller, at the end I followed this guide -> https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1355683     and I resolved!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is having trouble parsing baseurl because there is a space in the path between OL7.5 and Server.src.

Try putting it in quotes like this:

`baseurl="file:///run/media/root/OL7.5 Server.src/"`

Or using %20 in place of the space like this:

`baseurl=file:///run/media/root/OL7.5%20Server.src/`

Comment: Thank you so much! I answer you in my next post that unfortunately I was not able to solve the problem :(